# How to generate a random string in Python for a mission-critical application

Tags: randomness, cryptocurrency, pseudo-random-permutation

I'm trying to figure something out, but it is difficult for me. I need to generate a fully random string in Python. My current function is attached below. I just want to know whether this is secure and good for the project that I'm working on, a cryptocurrency type of website.

```
import random
import string

def get_random_string(length):
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(length))
    print(result_str)
```

Comment: How long a string, and how many? Randomness is a function of sample size. So for ONE key, just make it up: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/74833/23115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Random` module uses a cryptographically insecure PRG (Mersenne Twister). You want the `Secrets` module (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets)), which uses `urandom` on Linux, or `CryptGenRandom()` on Windows. In fact, I believe the following code should work (but have not verified it):

```
from secrets import choice
import string

def get_random_string(length):
    result_str = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(length))
    print(result_str)
```

If you are implementing things where misimplementation may cost you money in any way, I would suggest learning about practical cryptography before proceeding (as it is *very* easy to make small mistakes that can be a big pain). There are a variety of books people like, for example [Cryptography Engineering](https://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography-engineering/).